# Write the matrix $A$ in the form $A=BB$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix $A$ with $A=UDU^T, $ I need to prove the existence of a matrix $B$ such that $A=BB. $ It is easy to observe that $A$ can be written in the form:
$$A=UD^{1/2}D^{1/2}U^T=BB^T,$$ with $B:=UD^{1/2}.$ But I do not see how to write A in the required form $A=BB.$

Do you have any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: By the spectral theorem the matrix is diagonalisable with non-negative eigenvalues, therefore $$A=P\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\cdots, \lambda_n) P^{-1}=\left(P\operatorname{diag}(\sqrt{\lambda_1},\cdots, \sqrt{\lambda_n}) P^{-1}\right)^2$$

Comment: Isn't $U^TU = I$ or something? Put that in the middle of the two $D^{\frac 12}$ terms and see what $B$ can be. If it isn't, I apologize (although I believe it is, from the fact that $U$ is the first letter of "unitary", which are matrices satisfying $U^TU=I$). If this is true, this question is likely a duplicate of some other post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall that you can choose $U$ so that $U^{T}=U^{-1}$.  If $B=UD^{1/2}U^{T}$ then $BB=(UD^{1/2}U^{T})(UD^{1/2}U^{T})=UD^{1/2}D^{1/2}U^{T}$ because $U^{T}=U^{-1}$ so $BB =A$.

Comment: This nicely illustrates the power of conjugation and its homomorphicity.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Thank you. I have made that point clear now.